# Make Images appear in the same order as in media browser using get children?

Tags: images, order, get-children

I would really like my images to display in the same way I've ordered them in the media browser. What am I doing wrong?

```
$images =& get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID,
                                               'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                               'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                               'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                                               'order' => 'asc' ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** If you have reordered the images under the ***uploaded to this post*** in the media browser then they should have `menu_order>0` and you can get that order with

```
'orderby' => 'menu_order',                                               
'order' => 'asc'
```

**b)** If you haven't, then `menu_order=0` for all these images and you will need to use

```
'orderby' => 'ID',                                               
'order' => 'asc'
```

to get the same order (or date asc).

A solution for both cases could be like this, in pure SQL:

```
... ORDER BY menu_order ASC, ID ASC
```

If you try

```
'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',                                               
'order' => 'asc'
```

you will get

```
... ORDER BY menu_order, ID ASC
```

Since `get_children()` is using `get_posts()` there are some restriction on how extra fields can be added to the `orderby` and `order` parameters .

You can also use your custom query, where you have full control over the double ordering:

```
$sql="SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.* 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = %d  
AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%%')  
AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'attachment' 
AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_status <> 'trash' AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status <> 'auto-draft')  
ORDER BY {$wpdb->posts}.menu_order ASC,{$wpdb->posts}.ID ASC";

$images=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sql,$post->ID));
```